# Removing blood from colored clothes

Tags: cleaning, clothing

I got blood on my blue shirt. I would usually use peroxide, but last time I tried that, my shirt got ruined (colors got messed up). What is an easy way I can remove blood from my shirt without ruining the color.

Comment: Related: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/98/59 (white clothes)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Soak them in cold water immediately to prevent the blood from setting. Then scrub with washing soda (wear gloves) to loosen any that remains from the cloth.

After rinsing thoroughly, you can machine-wash on a cold cycle with additional washing soda and/or boosters as normally needed by your local water.

**Inspect carefully before drying:** if stains remain, repeat the soak+scrub to remove them. Once dried, you will find it exceedingly difficult to remove blood stains without also harming the color of your clothing.

Comment: How long should I soak for?

Comment: I'm a klutz and used cold water to great effect after many scrapes in times past. The cold water trick is surprisingly effective.

Comment: As long as is necessary, @michaelpri - the quicker you get the clothes into water, the less time (and scrubbing) you'll need. If you get it wrong, then rinse and repeat.

Comment: Just a side note - the reason you *do not* use hot water is because it will set the stain in and make it much harder to remove.

Comment: I want to ask the same for my Blue Jeans, i washed it immediately but still blood stain is there. Now few days passed. Any trick ?

Answer (score 6):

### Using lemon juice and salt on thick cloths

It is a slower method and effective on regular dresses but not on hard materials like carpets. Soak the cloth on the cold water for few mins. Immediately put the cloth in the lemon juice and salt solution mix. Rub/Massage it for 10-15mins. Rinse it and dry it on sunlight. lemon juice and sun are both capable of harming delicate fabrics. This can used on pants.

### Using tooth paste on delegate cloths

Apply the tooth paste on the blood stained area and allow it to dry. Rinse it using cold water. Wash the area with soap and rinse with cold water. It may used for polyester & cotton shirts.

### Using gentlest removal agents on silk

This mild method is only silk. Apply and rub the stained area with Saliva or dish washing liquid.

### Using baking powder with detergent powder on Jeans

Apply baking & detergent powder mix and keep it for 2-3 mins. Rinse it thoroughly with cold water.

*Repeat the steps on each method before drying them if stain persists.*