# How to get dried blood out of carpet

Tags: cleaning, carpet

So, one of my family members had injured themselves yesterday and dripped blood all over my carpet. I did not know until this morning when I got home from work. By now, the blood is dried and the carpet is white. How do I get the blood out? I don't want to try anything and make matters worse so I'm going to ask here. I also have pets in the house, so I would like a method safe for them if possible. Carpet is very different from clothing in that you can not soak it in a bowl or wash it in a machine, meaning that you have to do more than the "white shirt" tips say -.- Not a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean blood from white clothes](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-to-clean-blood-from-white-clothes)

Comment: Stackexchange will not be held responsible for assisting post-murder cleanup.

Comment: Uh? She fell off a chair in the kitchen. She couldn't find where she was bleeding from so she went to the bathroom and it dripped on the carpet ...

Comment: Carpet is very different from clothing in that you can not soak it in a bowl or wash it in a machine.

Comment: I do not believe this should be closed due to a "duplicate" seeing as there maybe the same basic suggestions, this is a slightly different type of fiber and as mentioned above, can't be placed in a washing machine or soaked like clothing can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had success without changing the color of the carpet, using oxyclean mixed with a few drops of carpet shampoo in a solution.

I mix one scoop into a spray bottle filled with very warm water. The powder should be completely dissolved before adding carpet cleaner to spray bottle. Gently mix in carpet cleaner. Solution will be foamy.

First, cold water soak to dissolve the dry blood. Blot up as much of the blood as you can with paper towels. DO NOT RUB.

Apply solution via the sprayer using the “stream” option. Carefully spray the area of stain until it is fully saturated. Let stand two or three minutes. Blot up solution with more paper towels until all detectable moisture is removed. It will probably take two applications to get all of the stain out.

If the stain is stubborn, on second application, use an white nylon brush to agitate solution on stain area. ***Immediately*** blot with a clean, white rag, using a clean area of rag for each blot. DO NOT RUB after scrubbing with brush.

Continue to blot with a *clean area of one or more rags* until all detectable moisture is removed. Fluff up nap with clean hand. Let dry overnight.

Answer (score 2):

Put some cold water on it and let it sit for a couple minutes (doesn't need to soaking wet, but enough to moisten and soften the blood).

Then drip some hydrogen peroxide over it and let it set until it stops fizzing, then gently dab it off with a cloth soaked in cold water.

This method, with slight modifications works great on bloody scrubs or menstruation accidents. Keep in mind that hydrogen peroxide can discolor colored items and may cause slight yellowing of something that is stark white, you may want to try a few drops in an inconspicuous place and let it sit for a couple hours just to be sure.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Peroxide will almost certainly change the color of the carpet...think of lightening your hair-uses peroxide. Also teeth whitening.

Comment: @M.Mat Most definitely... The only reason I even considered suggesting that was that while I have seen it "bleach" clothing, I have also been able to soak underwear and bloody scrubs with it and had no issues with the color... So I think it is very much effected by the type of dye and the type of fiber

Comment: I have used it on carpet and have had it noticeably change the color. I agree that it can be effective for clothing; especially polyester blend fabrics. 100% cotton garments I’ve noticed slight fade.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Ethanol or any other organic solvent. These are universal solvents and can clean blood stains easily.

Comment: Are you sure that they will not ruin the fibres in the carpet?

Answer (score 0):

If the stain is fresh, soak in cold water or use an eye dropper to directly apply hydrogen peroxide. If it's dry, brush it well to remove the surface deposit, then pretreat or soak in cool water with a laundry product containing enzymes, "You should never use a scented detergent when dealing with stains," Wash the item as usual. If the stain remains, rewash using the type of bleach that's safe for the fabric.

https://www.ecarpetstains.com/how-to-get-blood-out-of-carpet/