# Which chemical is used in hospitals to clean blood stains from bed sheets?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, stain

few days back i went to the hospital to meet my relative and i saw many blood soaked bed sheets and I wondered which chemical is used in hospitals to clean blood stains from bed sheets?

I googled it but could not find a answer (besides hydrogen peroxide)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean blood from white clothes](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-to-clean-blood-from-white-clothes)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the CDC guidelines on laundry in health care facilities. I hope this helps

https://www.cdc.gov/infectioncontrol/guidelines/environmental/background/laundry.html

The key points are:

- contamination from dirty laundry is very rare
- dealing with getting the dirty linens to the place where they are washed is more important than the actual washing process
- a pre-rinse, plenty of soap, ordinary bleach, and a good rinse, often an acid one, is all that is needed. Hot water (160 F) also helps.

Items that are not sheets (eg surgical gowns) may also be autoclaved.

Note: this article is concerned with the issue of contamination and not with how patients and their families might feel if they saw a stained sheet.